# Simple question about numpy matrix in python

Tags: python, numpy

Let's suppose I have a numpy matrix variable called MATRIX with 3 coordinates: (x, y, z).

Is acessing the matrix's value through the following code

```
myVar = MATRIX[0,0,0]
```

equal to

```
myVar = MATRIX[0,0][0]
```

or

```
myVar = MATRIX[0][0,0]
```

?

What about if I have the following code?

```
myTuple = (0,0)
myScalar = 0
myVar = MATRIX[myTuple, myScalar]
```

Is the last line equivalent to doing

```
myVar = MATRIX[myTuple[0], myTuple[1], myScalar]
```

I have done simple tests and it seems so, but maybe that is not so in all the cases. How do square brackets work in python with numpy matrices? Since day one I felt confused as how they work.

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure? I get a `TypeError` when I try any of this. If you have a tuple `MYTUPLE=(1,2,3)` then the only possible indices are `MYTUPLE[0]`, `MYTUPLE[1]` and `MYTUPLE[2]`.

Comment: Sorry, now that I see it, it's numpy matrices that I was refering to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you have a `array` instance rather than a `matrix`, since the latter only can have two dimensions.

`m[0, 0, 0]` gets the element at position (0, 0, 0).
`m[0, 0]` gets a whole subarray (a slice), which is itself a `array`. You can get the first element of this subarray like this: `m[0, 0][0]`, which is why both syntaxes work (even though `m[i, j, k]` is preferred because it doesn't have the unnecessary intermediate step).

Take a look at this ipython session:

```
rbonvall@andy:~$ ipython
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Sep 26 2009, 08:19:36) 
[...]

In [1]: import numpy.random

In [2]: m = numpy.random.random(size=(3, 3, 3))

In [3]: m
Out[3]: 
array([[[ 0.68853531,  0.8815277 ,  0.53613676],
        [ 0.9985735 ,  0.56409085,  0.03887982],
        [ 0.12083102,  0.0301229 ,  0.51331851]],

       [[ 0.73868543,  0.24904349,  0.24035031],
        [ 0.15458694,  0.35570177,  0.22097202],
        [ 0.81639051,  0.55742805,  0.5866573 ]],

       [[ 0.90302482,  0.29878548,  0.90705737],
        [ 0.68582033,  0.1988247 ,  0.9308886 ],
        [ 0.88956484,  0.25112987,  0.69732309]]])

In [4]: m[0, 0]
Out[4]: array([ 0.68853531,  0.8815277 ,  0.53613676])

In [5]: m[0, 0][0]
Out[5]: 0.6885353066709865
```

It only works like this for numpy `array`s.  Python built-in tuples and lists are not indexable by tuples, just by integers.

Comment: hmm, and what would m[0,0,0] yield?

Comment: The same as `m[0, 0][0]`, given that `len(m.shape) == 3`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to index a tuple with another tuple, so none of that code is valid.